# how to display man page in half screen when I split vim using vsp

Tags: linux, vim

ubuntu20 using raw vim without complex settings. now learn linux system programming. I need to watch the man page when I use vim editting prog.. now vsp to generate another half screen to display the man page. But man page still display in full screen.

[image]

I want to use right screen to display the stat 2 man page.

Answer (score 3):

You can open a terminal in a separate panel and open the man pages that you need from there:

Inside vim:

```
:vert term
```

This will open a terminal in a vertical panel, you can then switch between your code and the terminal by pressing `CTRL+W+W`.

You can now use the terminal to open the man pages that you need while also keeping your code in a separate vertical panel.

Comment: You can set it with `set splitright`. Append it to your .vimrc and the terminal will get on the right by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple method to achieve this objective.

```
$ man 2 stat > stat
$ vim stat # watch it use vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enabled the standard `:Man` command (like `:source $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/man.vim` in Vim; default in Neovim), you can do simply `:Man man` or `:vert Man man` etc.

Having `:set keywordprg=:Man` will also enable pressing <kbd>K</kbd> to show the man page for word under cursor.

Comment: when I type `:Man` in vim， show `E492: Not an editor command: Man`

Comment: I just know a little operation of vim, your suggestion is advanced for me. May I need learn some thing else first.

Comment: @MelvinLevett What's so advanced in typing `:source ...` command above?

Comment: I just operated as your text `:Man` and encountered an error. I am puzzled.